# Prove that ${\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}} X_i}$ and ${\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}} Y_i}$ are homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification, product-space

the problem posed is from Munkrees. Do you guys espouse my proof?? I feel as if I am missing something. Thank you!

Suppose that for each $i\in\mathbb{N}, X_i,$ and $Y_i$ are homeomorphic. Prove that $\displaystyle{\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}} X_i}$ and $\displaystyle{\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}} Y_i}$ are homeomorphic.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Let $f_i: X_i \to Y_i$ be homeomorphism for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $f: \displaystyle{\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}} X_i} \to \displaystyle{\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}} Y_i}$ is the required homeomorphism. So, $f$ is continous because each $f_i$ is continous. Thereby, $f^{-1}: \displaystyle{\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}} Y_i} \to \displaystyle{\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}} X_i}$ which is equivalent to $(y_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\to(f^{-1}_i(y_i))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. Thus, $f^{-1}$ is continous because each $f_i^{-1}$ is.

Comment: Please do not use displaystyle in titles

Comment: @amWhy I am sorry!

Comment: No problem, @rudinsimons12!  Just a matter of convention for trying to make titles of questions uniform/consistent in vertical space.

Comment: @amWhy Yes, I see what you mean

Comment: @rudinsimons12 In your proof, you jump from for each $i$ the spaces $X_i$ and $Y_i$ are homeomorphic (this is the given) to $\prod_i X_i$ and $\prod_i Y_i$ are homeomorphic (the claim to be proven). You haven't explained how the latter follows from the former. Hint: Can you produce a continuous map $\phi : \prod_i X_i\to \prod_i Y_i$? Can you produce one going the other way? Can you show that these maps are inverse to each other?

Comment: @jgon So my idea was that if they are homeomorphic, the products form a bijection. However, I am not really sure.

Comment: @jgon also, it is really cool you went to Yale, I am a senior and applied to Yale for Ph.D. in math and Ph.D. in econ. So cool you went there!

Comment: You claim the conclusion follows with no argument. So of course this is not a proof but an assertion of the claim you are trying prove (or you have left out many steps between the penultimate sentence and the last sentence).

Comment: @NapD.Lover Yes, I apologize for that. I was not thinking clearly, and I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your “proof” is no such thing. You just repeat the statement.

for a real proof, choose homeomorphisms $h_n: X_n \to Y_n$ for each $n$. From these construct $h: \prod_n X_n \to \prod_n Y_n$ in the obvious way, and use the universal property for maps into products to see that both $h$ and it’s inverse are continuous.

Or go high level and say that this follows from the fact that products in the category $\mathsf{Top}$ are limits and homeomorphisms are the category’s isomorphism. There is little topology in this fact.

**added** You have defined a sensible homeomorphism candidate. Depending on your text book and teacher demands you might have to add details to justify the claim that $f$ is continuous because all $f_n$ are (a theorem you can appeal to?) and maybe even on the bijectivity claim, depending on the amount of set theory covered.

Comment: Thank you Henno, I am editing what I put originally, sorry about that.

Comment: I edited the disgrace I put down initially. Please forgive me and hopefully the new solution I put down is better.

Comment: @rudinsimons12 see my added text for some remarks. How often are you allowed to say “ obviously “ in a proof? During education not as much as in later work....

Comment: Thank you Henno, I am using Munkrees textbook and the first chapter is all set theory so I will attach the continuity claim with the bijection, or I can use uniform convergence theorem i believe